# How to bind a proper date and time to an input in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to bind a current date and time to an input in Vue, which is a surprisingly hard task.

template:

```
<input type="datetime-local" v-model="dateRange.to">
```

script:

```
const dateRange = ref({
  from: null,
  to: inputDate
})

const today = new Date
const inputDate = today.toISOString().substring(0, 16)
```

With this code, I get time which is 2 hours earlier than my 'now'.
How can I 'make' a date, that would: 1. have proper time. 2. be bindable to input type daytime-local (without an advanced string processing)?

Comment: Try to use `moment.js` with `timezone` module instead.

Comment: i probably will, but I was curious how to do it with vanilla

Comment: You can study this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the timezone offset before calling `toISOString`.

```js
const today = new Date;
const inputDate = new Date(today - today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().slice(0, 16);
```